# How to make webpack-dev-server show .php files in browser instead of downloading?

Tags: php, webpack, webpack-dev-server

webpack-dev-server compiles successfully.

But when I navigate to index.php or any other *.php it just downloads.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're not running php, just a webserver

Comment: You r right. But how can I run php on webpack-dev-server?

Answer (score 0):

The webpack-dev-server is not intended for serving PHP files.

You could try and implement a cgi/fpm gateway and use with php-fpm, but why not just install nginx or apache instead?

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface